# Java 8 Streams: Read file word by word

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I use Java 8 streams a lot to process files but so far always line-by-line.

What I want is a function, which gets a `BufferedReader br` and should read an specific number of words (seperated by `"\\s+"`) and should leave the BufferedReader at the exact position, where the number of words was reached.

Right now I have a version, which reads the file linewise:

```
    final int[] wordCount = {20};
    br
          .lines()
          .map(l -> l.split("\\s+"))
          .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
          .filter(s -> {
              //Process s
              if(--wordCount[0] == 0) return true;
              return false;
          }).findFirst();
```

This obviously leaves the Inputstream at the position of the next line of the
20th word.
Is there a way to get a stream which reads less than a line from the inputstream?

**EDIT**
I am parsing a file where the first word contains the number of following words. I read this word and then accordingly read in the specific number of words. The file contains multiple such sections, where each section is parsed in the described function.

Having read all the helpful comments, it becomes clear to me, that using a `Scanner` is the right choice for this problem and that Java 9 will have a `Scanner` class which provides stream features (`Scanner.tokens()` and `Scanner.findAll()`).
Using Streams the way I described it will give me no guarantee, that the reader will be at specific position, after the terminal operation of the stream ([API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--)), therefore making streams the wrong choice for parsing a structure, where you parse only a section and have to keep track of the position.

Comment: "This obviously leaves the Inputstream at the position of the next line of the 20th word." It's far from obvious what state the input stream is in after executing this pipeline. I would assume that the stream is at EOF.

Comment: No, it stops after the number of words was reached, because `filter` returns true and the `findFirst` terminator.

Comment: Are you sure? *After execution of the terminal stream operation there are no guarantees that the reader will be at a specific position from which to read the next character or line.* [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--)

Comment: Interesting...I did not know that. In practise, it was always the next line :/

Comment: You can't rely on that. A `Stream` can be very useful for executing a pipeline on files, but only when you consume all lines. It's a bad fit for something like parsing a structure.

Comment: I guess, this means that Streams must not be used for the given problem at all. Thank you for clarifying that!

Comment: If your question is no longer relevant you may wish to delete it. Otherwise, try to clarify what you are asking, in the context of your new understanding of how that `Stream` works.

Comment: By the way, instead of `.map(l -> l.split("\\s+")).flatMap(Arrays::stream)` use `.flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\s+")::splitAsStream)` to avoid intermediate array creation and unnecessary match operations.

Comment: Why not use a `Scanner` and read each word with `scanner.next()`?

Comment: @Tunaki Plus one for `Scanner`. But note, if you use `Scanner` to process or skip the first N words, you have to continue to use the `Scanner` to process what follows. The reason is that `Scanner` buffers data from its source, even if that source already has its own buffer.

Comment: Also note that JDK 9 will have `Scanner.tokens()` and `Scanner.findAll()`, which will return (resp.) a stream of delimited tokens and a stream of pattern matches from the `Scanner`. But I don't think this actually helps to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: It would be nice to see your *original problem*. Why do you need `BufferedReader` to be stopped after word#20? What do you want to do with it after that? Probably it could be solved in some other way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your original problem: I assume your file looks like this:

```
5 a section of five words 3 three words
section 2 short section 7 this section contains a lot 
of words
```

And you want to get the output like this:

```
[a, section, of, five, words]
[three, words, section]
[short, section]
[this, section, contains, a, lot, of, words]
```

In general Stream API is badly suitable for such problems. Writing plain old loop looks a better solution here. If you still want to see Stream API based solution, I can suggest using my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) library which contains [`headTail()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#headTail-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method allowing you to easily write custom stream-transformation logic. Here's how your problem could be solved using the `headTail`:

```
/* Transform Stream of words like 2, a, b, 3, c, d, e to
   Stream of lists like [a, b], [c, d, e] */
public static StreamEx<List<String>> records(StreamEx<String> input) {
    return input.headTail((count, tail) -> 
        makeRecord(tail, Integer.parseInt(count), new ArrayList<>()));
}

private static StreamEx<List<String>> makeRecord(StreamEx<String> input, int count, 
                                                 List<String> buf) {
    return input.headTail((head, tail) -> {
        buf.add(head);
        return buf.size() == count 
                ? records(tail).prepend(buf)
                : makeRecord(tail, count, buf);
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```
String s = "5 a section of five words 3 three words\n"
        + "section 2 short section 7 this section contains a lot\n"
        + "of words";
Reader reader = new StringReader(s);
Stream<List<String>> stream = records(StreamEx.ofLines(reader)
               .flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\s+")::splitAsStream));
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The result looks exactly as desired output above. Replace `reader` with your `BufferedReader` or `FileReader` to read from the input file. The stream of records is lazy: at most one record is preserved by the stream at a time and if you short-circuit, the rest of the input will not be read (well, of course the current file line will be read to the end). The solution, while looks recursive, does not eat stack or heap, so it works for huge files as well.

---

Explanation:

The `headTail()` method takes a two-argument lambda which is executed at most once during the outer stream terminal operation execution, when stream element is requested. The lambda receives the first stream element (head) and the stream which contains all other original elements (tail). The lambda should return a new stream which will be used instead of the original one. In `records` we have:

```
return input.headTail((count, tail) -> 
    makeRecord(tail, Integer.parseInt(count), new ArrayList<>()));
```

First element of the input is `count`: convert it to number, create empty `ArrayList` and call `makeRecord` for the tail. Here's `makeRecord` helper method implementation:

```
return input.headTail((head, tail) -> {
```

First stream element is `head`, add it to the current buffer:

```
    buf.add(head);
```

Target buffer size is reached?

```
    return buf.size() == count
```

If yes, call the `records` for the `tail` again (process the next record, if any) and prepend the resulting stream with single element: current buffer.

```
            ? records(tail).prepend(buf)
```

Otherwise, call myself for the tail (to add more elements to the buffer).

```
            : makeRecord(tail, count, buf);
});
```

Comment: Thats a really awesome library!!